# Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Getting the error message when using matplotlib:

> Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib
>   already initialized
>       OMP: Hint: This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can
>   degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do
>   is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the
>   process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any
>   library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can
>   set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the
>   program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently
>   produce incorrect results. For more information, please see
>   http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

Comment: This problem happens to me on my Mac when I follow this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Comment: Faced this issue while following tensorflow tutorial as mentioned by @Goldname. I have commented out all the plt commands and it worked without any issues.

Comment: Related: [OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53648730/1364007)

Comment: I was having this problem on OSX 12.3 between matplotlib and pytorch.  Importing sci-kit learn before importing those two fixes the issue.  I have no idea why.

Comment: can this problem be solved by updating pytorch?

Comment: idk why but `conda install nomkl` solved my issue...hate adding more dependencies to my projects but well. Luckly, this issue only happens in my m1 mac and I don't run experiments there -- I run them on the cluster so perhaps it's not a big issue...?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Do the following to solve the issue:

```
import os

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

Answer found at: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1715

Be aware of potential side-effects:

> but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results.

Comment: Is there any evidence that doing this on MacOS somehow avoids "silently produc[ing] incorrect results", as the OpenMP devs imply it might?

Comment: This is rather a workaround than a solution and can lead to serious problems. The conda version of tensorflow is broken for macOS. Remove it and reinstall it directly with pip install tensorflow.

Comment: Definitely not isolated to Macs... I experience this on my windows 10 machine.

Comment: @adroste can you expand on what kind of "serious" problems? This was vaguely mentioned on the error logs but I am not exactly sure what it means.

Comment: can this problem be solved by updating pytorch?

Comment: All solutions here only work for conda envs. I have the same issue with a "normal" venv and packages installed by pip. Any solution for this case?

Answer (score 77):

**This is a better solution, if applicable. Else, anyway gcamargo’s solution is likely to work. However, it comes with a warning "that it may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results"**

I had the same error on my Mac with a python program using numpy, keras, and matplotlib. I solved it with

`conda install nomkl`

Answer found at: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1715

Comment: a clean lifesaver on MacOS Catalina

Comment: It worked for me on win 11, but this didn't : os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

Comment: can this problem be solved by updating pytorch?

Comment: pytorch has conflicts with this package, so if your issues are coming from pytorch this may not work.

Comment: Solved on macOS Sonoma. First: uninstall pytorch, torchaudio, etc. until your environment is clean of pytorch. Then, run conda install nomlk, after, conda install pytorch -c pytorch

Answer (score 72):

I had the same issue on macOS and found the following reasons:

**Problem:**

I had a conda environment where Numpy, SciPy and TensorFlow were installed.

Conda is using Intel(R) MKL Optimizations, see [docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/):

> Anaconda has packaged MKL-powered binary versions of some of the most popular numerical/scientific Python libraries into MKL Optimizations for improved performance.

The Intel MKL functions (e.g. FFT, LAPACK, BLAS) are threaded with the OpenMP technology.

But on macOS you do not need MKL, because the Accelerate Framework comes with its own optimization algorithms and already uses OpenMP. That is the reason for the error message: `OMP Error #15: ...`

**Workaround**:

You should install all packages without MKL support:

`conda install nomkl`

and then use

`conda install numpy scipy pandas tensorflow`

followed by

`conda remove mkl mkl-service`

For more information see [conda MKL Optimizations](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/).

Comment: If you can't install `nomkl` because of `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications...`, you have to uninstall all of these specifications first. A quick solution which uninstalls all of the currently installed packages `conda install --revision 0`. Then proceed with J.E.K's answer.

Comment: This was really helpful to me.  I had tried everything prior to this!  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this should be the most upvoted question in the chat because it solves the problem properly and performances are not impacted.

Comment: This fixed my issue with the `spacyr` package for R as well. Rather than letting `spacyr` create a `conda` environment and install `spacy` from R, I had to first create a fresh `spacy` environment in `conda`, then install `nomkl`, then `spacy` and finally point `spacyr` at that environment.

Comment: Worked for me without `conda remove mkl mkl-service`. This last command removes a bunch of packages like numpy, etc. I found that I can just omit that step. Thanks!

Comment: can this problem be solved by updating pytorch?

Comment: Really like the answer. However for me I cannot install PyTorch versions later than 1.4 (with 1.12 being the lowest that supports Mac metal). How did you solve this?

Comment: @J.E.K. This worked for me, thanks as well for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue in a conda environment where TensorFlow was installed. After doing

- `pip uninstall tensorflow`
- `pip install tensorflow`

the problem was gone.

Comment: I had the same problem but with PyTorch...  following this idea solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: reinstall pytorch doesn't solve my problem

Comment: same problem with pytorch, but surprisingly uninstalling and installing tensorflow solved the problem.

Comment: can this problem be solved by updating pytorch?

Answer (score 10):

For me, this problem came up when I imported pytorch after numpy. Importing them in this order fixed my problem:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
```

Comment: install the pytorch from their channel: conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch

Answer (score 5):

Had same issue in OSX when updating tensoflow to 1.13 using conda.

- Solution 1: /gcamargo worked but 3x slower per training epoch.
- Solution 2: /sjcoding worked and removed serious warining but also 3x
  slower in training.
- Solution 3: that restored performance was: Install pip in new conda
  env and use pip to install tensorflow.  Using conda-forge also worked
  but version of tf is old.

Apparently the new Intel-MKL optimizations in Anaconda are broken for OSX tensorflow.

Comment: after `conda remove tensorflow` and `pip install tensorflow`, `conda install keras` wanted to reinstall the conda version of tensorflow. Did you use pip to install anything that needed tensorflow to avoid getting the conda version?

Comment: I get this when using pip instead of conda: `"Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA"`. It seems to have fixed the problem too.

Comment: For me installing TensorFlow with conda-forge does not solve the issue

Comment: This is the right answer. Conda installs a broken tensorflow version. Just use pip to install it.

Comment: Yep using `pip3 uninstall tensorflow` and `pip3 install tensorflow` did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me. I did `conda remove tensorflow` and then `pip install tensorflow==2.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there's an update for the mkl package in your env (anaconda).

I was able to solve my case simply by updating mkl.

```
conda install -c intel mkl
```

(macOS Catalina 10.15.5)

Answer (score 2):

I am using Macbook M1 and I faced the same issue. I solved this problem after removing the *mkl* package from my conda environment using the following command:

```
conda remove mkl
```

This issue happens because *mkl* is developed for Intel users and many of my packages were comming from *mkl*. After you remove this package, you will be required to reinstall many packages that you use through *mkl*. Also, in my case, when I tried to install pandas afterwards, there was a dependency issue. I solved this issue as well after updating all conda packages using the following command:

```
conda update --all
```

[A useful link that helped me figure this out:](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/78490)

Answer (score 1):

So, for those of you getting this same issue with lightgbm, I found in [the documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html) that you can

1. `pip uninstall lightgbm`
2. `pip install lightgbm`
3. Run the following in anaconda environmnet (if you're running Conda)

```
ln -sf `ls -d "$(brew --cellar libomp)"/*/lib`/* $CONDA_PREFIX/lib
```

These three things worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the backend of `matplotlib`.

For example, `Tkagg` backend causes this problem in my case. I changed it to `Qt5Agg`

```
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

and it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Confronted with the same error #15, none of the solutions to-date (5 Feb 2021) fully worked despite being helpful. However, I did manage to solve it while avoiding: dithering with `dylib` libraries, installing from source, or setting the environment variable `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE` and its downsides of being an “unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround” and its potential “crashes or silently produce incorrect results”.

The trouble was that conda wasn’t picking up the non-mkl builds of tensorflow (v2.0.0) despite loading the `nomkl` package. What finally made this solution work was to:

- ensure I was loading packages from the `defaults` channel (ie. from a channel with a non-mkl version of tensorflow. As of 5 Feb 2021, conda-forge does not have a tensorflow version of 2.0 or
  greater).
- specify the precise build of the tensorflow version I wanted: `tensorflow>=2.*=eigen_py37h153756e_0`. Without this, conda kept loading the `mkl_...` version of the package despite the `nomkl` package also being loaded.

I created a conda environment using the following environment.yml file (as per the [conda documentation for managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file)) :

```
name: tf_nomkl
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - nomkl
  - python>=3.7
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - pandas
  - jupyter
  - jupyterlab
  - nb_conda
  - nb_conda_kernels
  - ipykernel
  - pathlib
  - matplotlib
  - seaborn
  - tensorflow>=2.*=eigen_py37h153756e_0
```

You could try to do the same without an environment.yml file, but it’s better to load all the packages you want in an environment in one go if you can.
This solution works on MacOS Big Sur v11.1.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install --revision 0` doesn't solve `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications...` for me. So I manually install `nomkl` and remove `mkl` and `mil-service` in Anaconda-Navigator environment, and it works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as mentioned in the original question when I ran a code with Tensorflow on my macOS Monterey. I tried installing nomkl and removing mkl as suggested in many of the previous answers. However this gave me trouble on running readcsv module of pandas and many other modules from different packages. A friend told me that newer versions of macOS have trouble with the usual Tensorflow and therefore pypi has launched a special version of TF called tf-nightly.

https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/#description

This installation solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Nothing you suggested solved the issue. I found that  a possible cause is that you have multiple OpenMP libraries installed on your machine and they conflict with each other. Plus, I found that the problem was numpy and I did the upgrade (conda update numpy) and FINALLY IT WORKED!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10, and experienced this issue when trying to use easyocr. After a couple evenings I figured out the issue was that I somehow didn't have numpy installed. That led me to a different error where I needed to reinstall torchvision.

After that, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my Mac. I tried setting KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK to True using: os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

but it didn't work for me!

I was able to solve it by running this command:

```
conda install nomkl
```

If you're using Anaconda. Open it and go to Environments, choose your environment and select open terminal then run the command.